# Why am I asked to vote on a flags to my own messages, when I am then prevented from voting on them?

Tags: bug, chat, flags

I have noticed that I am asked to decide on the validity of flags against messages of mine, but then am prevented from actually voting on them. That seems nonsense.

So why am I asked this in the first place?

(I am adding a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag here, because it seems fitting, but feel free to change this should I have overlooked something.)

Comment: I agree with this. I noticed that you can vote for "Not sure" though, which I guess could be renamed to "Hide this vote-election".

Comment: @Johannes: But why allow me to state my opinion, when I am only allowed to have one opinion? And, IIRC, voting "not sure" makes the flag needing more validators to get approved. So I _can_ somewhat counter my own flag. Well, can the chat please register a "not sure" vote from me now _automagically_ for any flag against me? And maybe, once the unicorns are at it, they should implement the same for the other few chat users as well? I mean, who would _not_ want this?

Comment: Apparently the flag system is not broken enough.